# parse string to key value object

Tags: java, arrays, string

I having the following string list

```
[customer=dan, Date=Wed Sep 16 06:42:18  1938,company=abbc] 
[customer=ben, Date=Sun May 19 13:12:51  1956,company=tss]
```

and i want to build from it list of list .
for example

```
<customer,dan>
<Date,Wed Sep 16 06:42:18  1938>
<company,abbc>
```

how should I parse this string?

Comment: Have you at least tried anything?

Comment: Don't use lists of lists. Create objects, with attributes and methods.

Comment: @JBNizet-Ok ,can you please provide example.thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of using a `List<List<String>`, you should use a `List<SomeObject>`, where `SomeObject` has an attribute `customer`, or type String, an attribute `date` of type Date, and an attribute `company`, or type String. And of course, you should choose a better name than SomeObject: a name that reflects what each of these lines represent. The answer of user000001 below explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split` method to parse the input strings (assuming that the company and customer names do not contain any commas or `]` characters. Something like this should work:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

class Element {

    String customer;
    Date date;
    String company;
    static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");

    void setDate(String date) {
        try {
            this.date = sdf.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            // Do something if parsing fails
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<customer," + customer + ">\n"
                + "<Date," + sdf.format(date) + ">\n"
                + "<company," + company + ">";
    }
}

public class ParseList {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("[customer=dan, Date=Wed Sep 16 06:42:18  1938,company=abbc]");
        list.add("[customer=ben, Date=Sun May 19 13:12:51  1956,company=tss]");

        List<Element> elementList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String str : list) {
            String[] arr = str.split("[,\\]]"); // Split the string
            Element element = new Element();
            element.customer = arr[0].split("=")[1]; // Split again on the equals
            element.setDate(arr[1].split("=")[1]);
            element.company = arr[2].split("=")[1];
            elementList.add(element);
        }

        for (Element element : elementList) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! when i tried your code i got dump in the System.out.println(element);
i think its related to the date

Comment: @BenHendo What do you mean you "got dump"? Perhaps is you run it through a debugger you will see where the problem is...